# Input Value not working with Livewire wire:model

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

What I am trying to do is getting some data from DB and showing it in `Input Value` fields but here the problem is that when I use `wire:model='some_input_name'` the value does not show up. And if I remove the  `wire:model` it shows the `value`

the code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="site_name">Site Name</label>
    <input wire:model='site_name' type="text" name="site_name" id="site_name"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Site Name" value="{{$settings->site_name}}">
    </div>
```

Is there anything wrong here?? What is the correct way to show value while binding the input field with livewire component?

Comment: Put the value of the `$site_name` property equal to `$settings->site_name` in the component class, not the view.

Comment: check video here https://youtu.be/ZYv9T0O4JOw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove `value="{{ $settings->site_name }}"` from your `<input>`, and use the following code in your component's `mount()` method:

```
$this->site_name = $settings->site_name;
```

This will preserve the two-way data binding, whilst letting you set an initial value.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to set an array of rules in your component, such as

```
$rules = [
 'settings.site_name' => 'required'
];
```

This validates you field values and allows them to be displayed. Futher reading is here in the [livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation).